# users.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to `map` user data to the render component (WidgetSm.jsx) using `useState` and `useEffect` hooks. But I'm getting this error in `console.dev`:

> Uncaught TypeError: users.map is not a function

How to resolve this error?

**My codes:**

Front/React:

WidgetSm.jsx:

```
import "./widgetSm.css";
import { Visibility } from "@material-ui/icons";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { userRequest } from "../../requestMethods";

export default function WidgetSm() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const getUsers = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await userRequest.get("users/?new=true");
        setUsers(res.data);
      } catch {}
    };
    getUsers();
  }, []);


  return (
    <div className="widgetSm">
      <span className="widgetSmTitle">New Join Members</span>
      <ul className="widgetSmList">
        {users.map((user) => (            //error located at this line
          <li className="widgetSmListItem" key={user._id}>
            <img
              src={
                user.img ||
                "https://cdn.elearningindustry.com/wp-content/themes/eli-2015/assets/images/mystery-man.png"
              }
              alt=""
              className="widgetSmImg"
            />
            <div className="widgetSmUser">
              <span className="widgetSmUsername">{user.username}</span>
            </div>
            <button className="widgetSmButton">
              <Visibility className="widgetSmIcon" />
              Display
            </button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

RequestMethods.js:

```
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = 'http://localhost:5000/api/';
const TOKEN = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("persist:root")).user).currentUser.accessToken;

export const publicRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
});

export const userRequest = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    headers: { token: `Bearer ${TOKEN}` }
});
```

Back/models:

Users.js:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        username: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        isAdmin: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        img: {
            type: String
        }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
)

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Comment: @Cyclonecode no it shouldn't, this is a valid jsx.

Comment: `res.data` isn't an array probably

Comment: KonradLinkowski `console.log(res.data)` inside `try catch` gave me an array of objects with users details

Comment: clg response with: `users: (2) [{...}, {...}]`

Comment: Put a debugger breakpoint on the offending line and inspect what the actual value of `users` is

Comment: "*I'm not sure if this error is related*" - no it's not. No `<table>` anywhere in the `WidgetSm` code, this is caused by some other component.

Comment: I can't find any problem with the logic of how you want to iterate over a list of elements. It looks like the problem is with the `users` state variable. Try to replace the `API` call with a mocked array of users. This should narrow down the problem space.

Comment: @RomanMahotskyi I was thinking to test again with a dummy static data (array). Would it helps to investigate my issue?

Comment: Sorry @Bergi, this doesn't help at all

Comment: @Ava Your code seems fine. `users` is initialised with an empty array, and the only `setUsers` call is done with another array as you purport (but we can't verify since we can't see the axios response). So either `res.data` is not an array, or there's something else going on, you'll need to do [further debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/).

Comment: @Ava Definitely. In such cases, the only way to find the problem is to remove possible parts of the code that could lead to the error.

Comment: One thing you can try to see if it works is to change your function `setUsers(JSON.parse(res.data))`

Comment: JSON parsing didn't help ...

Comment: Your data is formatting incorrectly somewhere. Add a debug point at `users.map` and check the value when the code stops running there. If the log with the axios request is fine maybe somewhere else something is changing.

Comment: i tried `{Object.values(users).map((user) => (  the rest of the code  ))}` instead of `{users.map((user) => ( //...)` and it helped me to render my component but it's messing username and showing only one line/user (meanwhile i have 2 users in DB)

Comment: One last thing to try: Remove the `Object.values` part, and change your function to `setUsers(res.data.users)`

Comment: Thank you @yomisimie now it works like charm :) i can see all users rendred with their usernames . Please consider adding this comment as an answer to accept it as solved !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One last thing to try:

Remove the `Object.values` part, and change your function to
`setUsers(res.data.users)`

The code is ok, the debug was ok, you just need a bit more attention to small details:

When in the debug you have `users: []` that mean it's an object with value, for the code to work directly with `res.data` the log should have been `[]` an empty array.

Happens to all of us at start, glad you could fix it!

Comment: Believe or not, `{Object.values(users).map((user) => (` and `{users.map((user) => (` both work fine with `res.data.users` . It seems that my problem was just with `res.data.users` only, because i had many documents in my Database like (users, products, charts, orders,...etc) and i have to specify which document should `axios` get the needed data to map them later.

Answer (score 0):

`{Object.values(users).map((user) => (            the rest of the code  ))}`
try using object.values instead of users.map

sometimes when u fetch data from some api to array ,it turnes to object ,
that worked for me

Comment: Why would that make a difference? Also, you don't show `Object.values` in the code you've shared. Please [edit] your post to explain exactly what code the user needs to change and why.

Comment: @Bra Him, you just copy pasted my original code above, i see no solution in your answer...

Comment: @Brahim you'll need to put a newline between the `\`\`\`` and the code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: ok, this is very interesting, @Bra Him code (using `Object.values`) **seems to work but not totally as expected**, it's like there's something missing. I'm getting the render back (page is no more blanc), but i'm getting only one user (i have 2 users in my DB), also, it doesn't fetch/render `username` ! What is missing??

Answer (score 0):

The `TypeError` indicates that whatever the user variable is at runtime time, it is not an array [js docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Since you have no provided any code for your requestMethods I cannot comment on any error there but I assume you are aiming for some output that follows...

`var users = [{userObject}, ...{finalUser}]`

where each userObject is in the form of the schema you provided. To resolve this mismatch I suggest you make several breakpoints/test cases to make sure you have an array with your user data before trying to render it.

If it is the case that you are just retrieving a single user with your request then the issue may be that it is not wrapped in an array and therefore would also throw a `TypeError` when attemping to use map on it. In this case modify your request output to always come wrapped in an array.

Comment: question updated with requestMethods code, kindly check it

Comment: also the only test i did was clg (res.data) inside try catch, it output me array of users i have in my DB, i tried to test with breakpoints but i can't manage to see any difference in console.dev .

Comment: @Ava could you please try and add an if before you return the DOM, i.e., if (users instanceof Array){ //return page} else {<div>Loading... </div>}